# De una diccionario que dejare abajo, quiero clasificarlos si los elementos de los valores para cada clave son igual entre si o diferentes

Tags: python, python-3.x, estructuras-de-datos

Las claves del diccionario equivale al numero de factura y el valor de estas claves es el estado del producto donde:
3 = Entregado, 2 = Pendiente, 1 = No entregado.

dependiendo de cuantos productos se llevo el tamaño del valor de cada clave aumenta, Ej. la factura con mas productos es la 0000010:[2,2,3,3,2] con 5 productos, donde 3 productos están pendientes y 2 productos entregados,

La cuestión es que quiero cambiar el estado de una factura si los estados de todos su productos están 3 = Entregado, si todos son iguales a 1 = No entregado, y si al menos tienen un producto pendiente o no entregado

Input.

```
resultado1={'0000001': [3, 3], '0000002': [2, 3], '0000003': [1], '0000004': [2, 2, 3], '0000005': [2], '0000006': [3], '0000007' : [1, 1], '0000008': [1,3], '0000009': [2,2], '0000010': [2,2,3,3,2]}
```

Output.

Elementos donde todos sus valores de cada clave son igual a 3 'Factura entregada':
0000001: [3,3], 0000006: [3]

Elementos donde al menos uno de sus valores es igual a 2 o 1 'factura pendiente':
0000002: [2, 3], 0000004: [2, 2, 3], 0000005: [2], 0000008: [1,3],0000009: [2,2],0000010 : [2,2,3,3,2]

Elementos donde todos sus valores de cada clave es igual a 1 'factura no entregada:

0000003: [1], 0000007 : [1, 1]

**Estoy intentando con eso pero me hace falta clasificar No entregado y que queden junto con su clave**

```
resultado1={'0000001': [3, 3], '0000002': [2, 3], '0000003': [1], '0000004': [2, 2, 3], '0000005': [2], '0000006': [3], '0000007' : [1, 1], '0000008': [1,3], '0000009': [2,2], '0000010': [2,2,3,3,2] }
u=[]
p=[]
e=[]
ne=[]   
            
for estado in resultado1.values():
    #print(estado)
    
    if 2 not in estado :
        e.append((estado))
    else:
        p.append((estado))


for i in e:
    if 3 in i:
        u.append(i)



for i in u:
    if  1 in u:
        print('Z',i)
 
for i in ne:
    print('No entregado',i)

for i in u: 
    print('Entregado',i)

for i in p:
    print('Pendiente',i)
```

===================

OUTPUT:

```
Entregado [3, 3]
Entregado [3]
Entregado [1, 3]
Pendiente [2, 3]
Pendiente [2, 2, 3]
Pendiente [2]
Pendiente [2, 2]
Pendiente [2, 2, 3, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: He corregido mi pregunta espero puedas echarle un vistazo